# time capsule router history log

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, web-browsing, router

Does the time capsule router log web history? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not.  You will need to incorporate a 3rd party device or software for that.  Expand your question to include your needs and someone may be able to help you further.

Comment: that pretty much helped me...now i just need to find a service :)